# Hibernate+swing check login/password

Tags: java, hibernate, swing

Hello i have a two questions. What is best way to check/find is exist some value. For example i have in my db [image: db_table]

and i wanna check in my login swing app someone login and pass.
How can i build a query?
i was try 
`EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("library");
                EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
                entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from users");
                //query.setParameter(1,forLogin.getText());
                //query.setParameter(2,forPassword.getText());
                System.out.println(query.getFirstResult());`
But always is say 0. Even when i add parameter with good value is still 0. I know is function .find() but it can take only(?) id parametr or i dont know how can i pick it using other column. And second question. I need in every class create entitymanager+factory when i wanna use db or is some other way? Because when i wanna use it when i open in other class is saying "session closed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You have to replace the class of the entity and the field of the user name and password

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("library");
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
// Query with where clausel
// I 'lower' the user name and use a TypedQuery
// the password should be case sensentive
TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery("from users u where lower(u.username) = :name and u.password = :password", User.class);
query.setParameter("name", "foo");
query.setParameter("password", "pwd");
try {
    User user = query.getSingleResult();
    System.out.println("User found");
} catch( javax.persistence.NoResultException e ){
    System.out.println("No user found");
}
```